# How to check if a relation represented as a matrix (list of lists) is antisymmetric?

Tags: matrix, scheme

How can I check if a relation represented as a matrix (list of lists) is antisymmetric?

For example, the function should return true for;

```
(antisymm ((1 1 0) (0 0 1) (0 0 0)))
```

Example:

```
(antisymm ((1 1 0) (0 0 1) (0 0 0))) returns #t
(antisymm ((1 1 0) (0 0 1) (0 1 0))) returns #f
```

Comment: I think that matrix in your example isn't antisymmetric.

Comment: Can you write a test to check if a matrix is symmetric?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be dealing with matrices (or any data type) the first thing to do is to write some abstractions.  Matrices are not lists of lists: they might be *represented* as lists of lists, but they're matrices.

So let's assume some abstractions which I will not write:

- `matrix-rows` tells you how many rows a matrix has;
- `matrix-cols` tells you how many columns a matrix has;
- `matrix-ref` retrieves an element of a matrix.

I will also assume zero-based indexing (which is not what mathematicians assume).

You might also want a `make-matrix` function.

Then it is relatively easy to write a symmetry checker:

```
(define (symmetry-test? m symmetry-predicate?)
  ;; Zero-based indexing assumed
  (define max-row (- (matrix-rows m) 1))
  (define max-col (- (matrix-cols m) 1))
  (cond
    ((not (= max-row max-col))
     (error "not square"))
    ((= max-row 0)
     ;; 1x1 is symmetric by definition
     #t)
    (else
     (let check ((row 1)
                 (col 0))
       ;; Note we need to check diagonal elts for skew case
       (cond
         ((> col max-col)
          #t)
         ((> col row)
          (check (+ row 1) 0))
         ((symmetry-predicate? (matrix-ref m row col)
                               (matrix-ref m col row))
          (check row (+ col 1)))
           (else
            #f))))))
```

And now

```
(define (matrix-symmetric? m)
  ;; a matrix is symmetric if a[r,c] = a[c,r] for all r, c
  (symmetry-test? m =))

(define (matrix-skew? m)
  ;; a matrix is skew is a[r,c] = - a[c,r] for all r, c
  (symmetry-test? m (λ (a b) (= a (- b)))))
```

For additional bonus points: why does this show that a list of lists is an absolutely terrible representation for a matrix?